# Does $\sum_{n \ge 2}{(n\log^2(n))^{-1}}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis

Does $$\sum_{n \ge 2}(n\log^2(n))^{-1}$$ converge? If at all possible, an explanation of why would be great!

Comment: By $\log^{2}(n)$ do you mean $(\log(n))^{2}$ or $\log(\log(n))$?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood It should be $(log(n))^2$, sorry

Comment: @PeterGriffin I changed n\ log^2(n) to n\log^2(n), so that instead of $n\ log^2(n)$ you see $n\log^2(n)$.  That is standard.

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy condensation test? Otherwise, comparison with the integral $\int_2^\infty \frac{dt}{t(\log t)^2}$ settles it.

Comment: @DanielFischer Cauchy condensation test is perfect, thanks! I'll accept the answer as soon as the timer allows me to.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks, I'll use that from now on.

Comment: @user_of_math Since $\log^p n$ means $(\log n)^p$ here, the series converge for all $p > 1$ (integer or not) and diverges for $p\leqslant 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), the series converges
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^nf(2^n) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 \log^2  2 }$$